# How to upload multiple images in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to upload multiple images in database using active form in `yii2`. I also tried

This is my view

```
<div class="kv-avatar center-block">
        <?= $form->field($photoModel, 'st_image[]')->fileInput(['class' => 'file-loading avatar-1'])->label(false)?>
            </div>
 <div class="kv-avatar center-block">
        <?= $form->field($photoModel, 'st_image[]')->fileInput(['class' => 'file-loading avatar-1'])->label(false)?>
             </div>
```

Controller

```
 $photoModel->st_image = UploadedFile::getInstance($photoModel,'st_image');
            foreach( $photoModel->st_image as $key=>$file)
            {
                $img_name = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
                $file->saveAs($path . $img_name . '.' . $file->extension);
                $images = $img_name . '.' . $file->extension;
                $photoModel->user_id = $id;
                $photoModel->st_image = $images;
                $photoModel->save(false);   
                $photoModel = new Photo();
    }
```

but it give me error

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

can anyone help me please

Comment: Please be attentive and read http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-file-upload.html#uploading-multiple-files

Answer (score 1):

For muiltiple instances you should call `UploadedFile::getInstances()` instead of `UploadedFile::getInstance()`